# anksvn forbidden exception. access to // forbidden

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, ankhsvn

I am getting the following error when I try to check C# 2008 application code into the latest version of anksvn.

```
error message:
SharpSvn.SvnReposito​ryIOForbiddenExcepti​on: Commit failed (details follow): ---> SharpSvn.SvnReposito​ryIOForbiddenExcepti​on: Access to '/svn/city/!svn/me' forbidden
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientAr​gs.HandleResult(SvnC​lientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientAr​gs.HandleResult(SvnC​lientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.C​ommit(ICollection`1 paths, SvnCommitArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at Ankh.Services.Pendin​gChanges.PendingChan​geHandler.<>c_​_DisplayClass1b.<​Commit_CommitToRepos​itory>b__19(Objec​t sender, ProgressWorkerArgs e)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerS​ervice.ProgressRunne​r.Run(Object arg
```

I am hoping you can suggest what I can do to resolve the problem.
 Possibly can you point me to a link that will resolve the problem and/or tell me how to resolve this problem?

I do not know where this location is at. I can check code out from anksvn but I can not check code into subversion.

This is the second time that I have worked with anksvn.

I am told that have I have access to everything that I need access to.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the code, but not check in your changes?

Can you use the Subversion command line? Check out the directory from there, make a change, and then see if you can commit your code.

The error is saying you don't have permission. Maybe trying this from the command line will give you a better idea what the error could be.

Comment: Using anksvn, can you tell me and/or point me to a reference that tells me how to checkin code from the command line using anksvn? As far as I know, the only way to check in code and check out code is to use the anksvn client that is connected to visual studio

Comment: Download [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net). This is another Subversion client. It also comes with a command line Subversion client too. TortoiseSVN works through Windows Explorer and should be compatible with the AnkhSVN client. (Make sure that they're both version 1.7.x of the Subversion client). Sometimes, looking at your Subversion working directory through another client application can help you deduce the error.